# how to show the "ñ" character on variable in php

Tags: php

I'm a beginner in php. I'm trying to print a variable that contains the letter "ñ" but it doesn't print correctly. It appears a question mark. But in the array it prints ok. Why is this and how can I fix it?. My codification is UTF-8 and this is my code

```
<?php header('content-type:text/html;charset=utf-8');

  $vowels = array('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u');
  $consonants = array('b','c','d','f','g','h','j','k','l','m','n','ñ','p','q','r','s','t','v','w','x','y','z');
  $word = "wxyzñ";
  echo $word;
  echo "<br>" . $word[4] . " " . $consonants[11] ;

?>
```

The $word prints ok even without the header, but when try to get that only character in the word it doesn't work. And in the array the "ñ" prints ok. I tryed to convert the $word variable to an array with str_split, but same result. Also I tryed with the html_entities, but same result. Please help. Thanks!

Comment: Try using the HTML code: `&ntilde;` and so on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UTF-8 is a multibyte encoding. That's mean that a character can be represented by more than one byte. The `ñ` char is in fact composed by two bytes: `C3` and `B1`. With `$word[4]` you only get `C3`, and `C3` doesn't means anything in UTF-8 (so your browser print a question mark instead). What you should do is retrieve the two byte together. You can do that with `mb_substr`.

```
$char = mb_substr($word, 4, 1);
```

Comment: @user2558831 Works for me https://3v4l.org/aW0D8 , where's your code? Did `echo $word` prints the characters correctly?

Comment: $word prints the characters correctly, even if I access the 11th position of the array it prints correctly the character 'ñ', but not if put $word[4]

Comment: I explained why $word[4] can't works. Did you read my answer?

Comment: if I echo $char with the code you posted it prints the same question mark